# Enable and disable a checkbox on the user role in Asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I am using a **View** for adding a new user in Asp.net MVC4(Razor view engine).
When a user which is in Admin role adds a new user, then i want to show a check-box to user which will say
IsAdmin( for adding new user to Admin role) and when a new anonymous user register himself,then this check-box should not appear. **For both case i want to use same View**
I am using Asp.netMVC4 Simple-membership.

So, Please tell me how i can achieve the same

Comment: Did you consider an If Else statement?

Comment: I can use it but i don't how to check the roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your site is set up, so it's hard to answer, but...

I will assume you're passing a model to your view from your controller.

If so, add a property to your model (in fact, this is a great time to use a ViewModel) of type bool. Make sure the value of your bool reflects the user role's rights as admin (true or false).

So, something like

```
public bool IsAdmin
{
    get { return _isAdmin;}
    set 
    {
        _isAdmin = IsPartOfAdminRoleQuery();
    }
}
```

Then, in your view, just call your Model like (you may need to use a Lamba or similar depending on how your model is set up)

```
@if (Model.IsAdmin) 
//logic
```

Comment: Ok i am using the same in MY ViewModel